# accidental withdraw

Tags: wallet

So I deposited some bitcoin into my SR account, but then like an idiot I tried to withdraw the bitcoin using the same deposit address.  Technically it shouldn't have any effect since I basically withdrew my bitcoin from my e-wallet, to my e-wallet.  However, in my history it shows the bitcoin was withdrawn but its nowhere to be found.

Any way to get this back or is it gone forever?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a day, SR has been reported to process btc transactions very slowly before.  If it is still missing after a day open a support ticket with them.